# Incorrect CPU speed in Windows 8.1

Tags: cpu, windows-8.1, overclocking, amd-athlon

I have recently tried to overclock a AMD Athlon II X2 270 on a MSI GF615M-P33 V2 motherboard. I changed the FSB from 200 to 206, that's an increase of 102 MHZ from 3.4 GHZ.. no biggie.
On reboot I got an error message saying that the overclocking failed. I entered the BIOS and changed everything to its default setting, but apparently my CPU now has only 2.73 GHZ according to task manager. In CPU-Z and in BIOS the frequency is still 3.4 GHZ though...

So my question is, what is broken and how can it be fixed? Which one is the real frequency? Will it affect the performance?

Comment: Could be the system down-clocking to save energy when not under heavy load.  Is "[PowerNow!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerNow!)" enabled?  Does the clock speed stay the same if you start running a CPU-intensive program?

Comment: Mine does this. If your (Constantin's) PC wasn't doing this before, perhaps one of the settings changed while overclocking was to enable speedstep or whatever?

Comment: Cool'n'Quiet is disabled and the frequency stays the same under heavy load.

Comment: Ok now it's reading the correct clock speed. What I had to do was to take out the CPU and reinsert it.